# Using Python and lxml to validate XML against an external DTD

Tags: python, xml, validation, lxml, dtd

I'm trying to validate an XML file against an external DTD referenced in the doctype tag. Specifically:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-export SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd">
...the rest of the document...
```

I'm using Python 3.3 and the lxml module. From reading http://lxml.de/validation.html#validation-at-parse-time, I've thrown this together:

```python
enexFile = open(sys.argv[2], mode="rb") # sys.argv[2] is the path to an XML file in local storage.
enexParser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True)
enexTree = etree.parse(enexFile, enexParser)
```

From what I understand of validation.html, the lxml library should now take care of retrieving the DTD and performing validation. But instead, I get this:

```
$ ./mapwrangler.py validate notes.enex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mapwrangler.py", line 27, in <module>
    enexTree = etree.parse(enexFile, enexParser)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3239, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:69955)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102257)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1789, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102516)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1684, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101442)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1134, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97069)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91275)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91757)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Validation failed: no DTD found !, line 3, column 43
```

This surprises me, because if I turn off validation, then the document parses in just fine and I can do `print(enexTree.docinfo.doctype)` to get

```
$ ./mapwrangler.py validate notes.enex
<!DOCTYPE en-export SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd">
```

So it looks to me like there shouldn't be any problem finding the DTD.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you add `no_network=False` when constructing the parser object? See "Parser options" here: http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much @mjzn! That was it. Could you write that up in an answer so I could award you reputation for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `no_network=False` when constructing the parser object. This option is set to `True` by default.

From the documentation of parser options at http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers:

> no_network - prevent network access when looking up external documents (on by default)

Answer (score 0):

For a reason I still don't know, my problem was related to where the XML catalog was located on my local file system.

In my case, I use an XML editor that has a tight integration with a component content management system (CCMS, in this case SDL Trisoft 2011 R2). When the editor connects to the CCMS, DTDs, catalog files and a bunch of other files are synced. These files end up on the local file system in:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Trisoft\InfoShare Client\[id]\Config\DocTypes\catalog.xml
```

I could not get that to work. Simply COPYING the whole catalog to another location fixed things, and this works:

```
f = r"path/to/my/file.xml"
# set XML catatog file path
os.environ['XML_CATALOG_FILES'] = r'C:\DATA\Mydoctypes\catalog.xml'
# configure parser
parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, no_network=True)
# validate
try:
   valid = etree.parse(f, parser=parser)
    print("This file is valid against the DTD.")
except etree.XMLSyntaxError, error:
   print("This file is INVALID against the DTD!")
   print(error)
```

Obviously this is not ideal, but it works.

Could it be something to do with file permissions, or perhaps that good old "file path too long" problem in Windows? I have not tried whether a symbolic link would work.

I am using Windows 7, Python 2.7.11 and the version of lxml is (3.6.0).